# How does one interpret the following integral: $g(z)=\int_{\mid Z \mid > z} Z^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, notation

I am reading Freedman's "A Note on Screening Regression Equations" and I'm not quite sure how to understand the second equation shown in the paragraph below:

[image]

If more context is needed, [here is the full paper](http://www.public.asu.edu/~gasweete/crj604/readings/1983-Freedman%20(Screening%20Regression%20Equations).pdf).

Comment: It's the integral of $Z^2$ over the space of $Z$ with $|Z| > z$. This space is the union of two intervals, but the notation applies to more complicated sets as well.

Comment: I am still not sure about how would proceed with the evaluation of that integral. In full notation, I'd expect the differential to tell me the variable being integrated over. Should I take the expression to be identical to $\int_{\mid Z \mid > z} z^2 \delta z$? As the space depends on random $Z$, is $g(z)$ also random?

Comment: It seems to me that $$ g(z) = \int_{\{|Z| > z\}} Z^2 \, \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega) = \Bbb{E}[Z^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{|Z| > z\}} ], $$ which is the expectation of $Z^2$ with cut-off $|Z| > z$. Since $Z$ has pdf $f_Z(t) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-t^2/2}$, it is simply $$ g(z) = \int_{\{|t| > z\}} t^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2} \, dt. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense you are right to fail to understand this: It is not expressed in anything that appears (to me?) to be standard language.

However, let us note a broader context: First, Freedman says

> Let $Z$ be standard normal and $\Phi(z) = P\{|Z|>z\}.$

Later he says

> Clearly, $$ E\{Z^2 \mid |Z|>z\} = g(z)/\Phi(z). $$

Since we know that
$$
\operatorname{E}(Z^2 \mid |Z|>z) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{u\,:\,|u|>z} u^2 \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\Phi(z)} \, du = \sqrt{\frac 2 \pi} \int_z^\infty u^2 \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\Phi(z)} \, du,
$$
it seems we must conclude that
$$
g(z) = \int_{\{ |Z|>z \}} Z^2
$$
was intended to mean
$$
\int_{u\,:\,|u|>z} u^2 \varphi(u)\,du = \int_{u\,:\,|u|>z} u^2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} \, du.
$$